# How to set the status of a BIM360 Project using Postman or .NET

Tags: .net, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have been successful in following this tutorial in creating a new Project: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/account-admin/create-project/#step-1-create-a-new-project.

However I am unsure of how to change the status of a created Project in BIM360 from `active` to `archived`. I have looked around for any documentation on this topic but I haven't found any. Is this action possible and if so, what is the request to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can PATCH a project and update its status:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/e3d5ef8d-5c37-4b9d-925d-1e6d24753ace/projects/aca11a7a-bd17-47cd-ab99-6548d0e6fe25' \
  -X 'PATCH' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 9ezBnx9Rd5D1xG4KMt6b72T4w0MG' \
  -d '{"status":"archived"}'
```

See doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-PATCH/).